# Create a hash from a string and an uinteger in C#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, hash, md5

I need to create a hash from a string like this code:

```
private static function core_md5(_arg_1:Array, _arg_2:uint):Array{
    var _local_8:uint;
    var _local_9:uint;
    var _local_10:uint;
    var _local_11:uint;
    _arg_1[(_arg_2 >> 5)] = (_arg_1[(_arg_2 >> 5)] | (128 << (_arg_2 % 32)));
    _arg_1[((((_arg_2 + 64) >>> 9) << 4) + 14)] = _arg_2;
    var _local_3:uint = 1732584193;
    var _local_4:uint = 4023233417;
    var _local_5:uint = 2562383102;
    var _local_6:uint = 271733878;
    var _local_7:uint;
    while (_local_7 < _arg_1.length) {
        _arg_1[_local_7] = ((_arg_1[_local_7]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 1)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 1)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 2)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 2)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 3)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 3)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 4)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 4)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 5)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 5)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 6)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 6)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 7)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 7)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 8)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 8)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 9)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 9)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 10)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 10)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 11)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 11)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 12)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 12)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 13)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 13)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 14)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 14)]) || (0));
        _arg_1[(_local_7 + 15)] = ((_arg_1[(_local_7 + 15)]) || (0));
        _local_8 = _local_3;
        _local_9 = _local_4;
        _local_10 = _local_5;
        _local_11 = _local_6;
        _local_3 = ff(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 0)], 7, 3614090360);
        _local_6 = ff(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 1)], 12, 3905402710);
        _local_5 = ff(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 2)], 17, 606105819);
        _local_4 = ff(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 3)], 22, 3250441966);
        _local_3 = ff(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 4)], 7, 4118548399);
        _local_6 = ff(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 5)], 12, 1200080426);
        _local_5 = ff(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 6)], 17, 2821735955);
        _local_4 = ff(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 7)], 22, 4249261313);
        _local_3 = ff(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 8)], 7, 1770035416);
        _local_6 = ff(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 9)], 12, 2336552879);
        _local_5 = ff(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 10)], 17, 0xFFFF5BB1);
        _local_4 = ff(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 11)], 22, 2304563134);
        _local_3 = ff(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 12)], 7, 1804603682);
        _local_6 = ff(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 13)], 12, 4254626195);
        _local_5 = ff(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 14)], 17, 2792965006);
        _local_4 = ff(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 15)], 22, 1236535329);
        _local_3 = gg(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 1)], 5, 4129170786);
        _local_6 = gg(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 6)], 9, 3225465664);
        _local_5 = gg(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 11)], 14, 643717713);
        _local_4 = gg(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 0)], 20, 3921069994);
        _local_3 = gg(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 5)], 5, 3593408605);
        _local_6 = gg(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 10)], 9, 38016083);
        _local_5 = gg(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 15)], 14, 3634488961);
        _local_4 = gg(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 4)], 20, 3889429448);
        _local_3 = gg(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 9)], 5, 568446438);
        _local_6 = gg(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 14)], 9, 3275163606);
        _local_5 = gg(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 3)], 14, 4107603335);
        _local_4 = gg(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 8)], 20, 1163531501);
        _local_3 = gg(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 13)], 5, 2850285829);
        _local_6 = gg(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 2)], 9, 4243563512);
        _local_5 = gg(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 7)], 14, 1735328473);
        _local_4 = gg(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 12)], 20, 2368359562);
        _local_3 = hh(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 5)], 4, 4294588738);
        _local_6 = hh(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 8)], 11, 2272392833);
        _local_5 = hh(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 11)], 16, 1839030562);
        _local_4 = hh(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 14)], 23, 4259657740);
        _local_3 = hh(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 1)], 4, 2763975236);
        _local_6 = hh(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 4)], 11, 1272893353);
        _local_5 = hh(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 7)], 16, 4139469664);
        _local_4 = hh(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 10)], 23, 3200236656);
        _local_3 = hh(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 13)], 4, 681279174);
        _local_6 = hh(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 0)], 11, 3936430074);
        _local_5 = hh(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 3)], 16, 3572445317);
        _local_4 = hh(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 6)], 23, 76029189);
        _local_3 = hh(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 9)], 4, 3654602809);
        _local_6 = hh(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 12)], 11, 3873151461);
        _local_5 = hh(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 15)], 16, 530742520);
        _local_4 = hh(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 2)], 23, 3299628645);
        _local_3 = ii(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 0)], 6, 4096336452);
        _local_6 = ii(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 7)], 10, 1126891415);
        _local_5 = ii(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 14)], 15, 2878612391);
        _local_4 = ii(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 5)], 21, 4237533241);
        _local_3 = ii(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 12)], 6, 1700485571);
        _local_6 = ii(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 3)], 10, 2399980690);
        _local_5 = ii(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 10)], 15, 4293915773);
        _local_4 = ii(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 1)], 21, 2240044497);
        _local_3 = ii(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 8)], 6, 1873313359);
        _local_6 = ii(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 15)], 10, 4264355552);
        _local_5 = ii(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 6)], 15, 2734768916);
        _local_4 = ii(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 13)], 21, 1309151649);
        _local_3 = ii(_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 4)], 6, 4149444226);
        _local_6 = ii(_local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 11)], 10, 3174756917);
        _local_5 = ii(_local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _local_4, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 2)], 15, 718787259);
        _local_4 = ii(_local_4, _local_5, _local_6, _local_3, _arg_1[(_local_7 + 9)], 21, 3951481745);
        _local_3 = (_local_3 + _local_8);
        _local_4 = (_local_4 + _local_9);
        _local_5 = (_local_5 + _local_10);
        _local_6 = (_local_6 + _local_11);
        _local_7 = (_local_7 + 16);
    };
    return ([_local_3, _local_4, _local_5, _local_6]);
}

private static function rol(_arg_1:uint, _arg_2:uint):uint{
    return (((_arg_1 << _arg_2) | (_arg_1 >>> (32 - _arg_2))));
}

private static function cmn(_arg_1:uint, _arg_2:uint, _arg_3:uint, _arg_4:uint, _arg_5:uint, _arg_6:uint):uint{
    return ((rol((((_arg_2 + _arg_1) + _arg_4) + _arg_6), _arg_5) + _arg_3));
}

private static function ff(_arg_1:uint, _arg_2:uint, _arg_3:uint, _arg_4:uint, _arg_5:uint, _arg_6:uint, _arg_7:uint):uint{
    return (cmn(((_arg_2 & _arg_3) | (~(_arg_2) & _arg_4)), _arg_1, _arg_2, _arg_5, _arg_6, _arg_7));
}

private static function gg(_arg_1:uint, _arg_2:uint, _arg_3:uint, _arg_4:uint, _arg_5:uint, _arg_6:uint, _arg_7:uint):uint{
    return (cmn(((_arg_2 & _arg_4) | (_arg_3 & ~(_arg_4))), _arg_1, _arg_2, _arg_5, _arg_6, _arg_7));
}

private static function hh(_arg_1:uint, _arg_2:uint, _arg_3:uint, _arg_4:uint, _arg_5:uint, _arg_6:uint, _arg_7:uint):uint{
    return (cmn(((_arg_2 ^ _arg_3) ^ _arg_4), _arg_1, _arg_2, _arg_5, _arg_6, _arg_7));
}

private static function ii(_arg_1:uint, _arg_2:uint, _arg_3:uint, _arg_4:uint, _arg_5:uint, _arg_6:uint, _arg_7:uint):uint{
    return (cmn((_arg_3 ^ (_arg_2 | ~(_arg_4))), _arg_1, _arg_2, _arg_5, _arg_6, _arg_7));
}
```

But i do not find function who take in argument a string and an uinteger/integer in Framework .NET.

Does HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash make the same thing as this function ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Could you help me ?

Cordialy

Comment: Do you actually need an MD5 hash? .NET has a perfectly fine MD5 implementation. MD5 hashes bytes, so you can just serialize your data however you see fit (e.g. write the string as UTF16, and the integer as its 4-byte representation, in either order), and then pass the resulting bytes to the MD5 algorithm for hashing.

Comment: Thank you, yes i need a MD5 hash, i will try.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example of how you might accomplish your goal:

```
static byte[] HashMd5(string text, int value)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
    using (System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm hash =
        new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5Cng())
    {
        writer.Write(text);
        writer.Write(value);
        writer.Flush();

        stream.Position = 0;

        return hash.ComputeHash(stream);
    }
}
```

If all you want is *some* hash, the above should work for any scenario.

However, there are many alternatives; hashes are often used for comparison with a previously-computed value, and in scenarios where the hash is compared to that computed earlier, you would need to ensure that the encoding of your data is always done exactly the same. In the above, the following are important to keep in mind:

- The C# `string` object is encoded using the default for `BinaryWriter` of UTF8
- The C# `int` value is encoded as four bytes in little-endian format

In .NET, if you just always use the exact code I've shown, it will always produce the same hash value. If you have to recomputed the hash in some other environment, that other environment may have different defaults or encoding rules (e.g. to convert its text to UTF8), which you'll have to make sure are done in exactly the same way. Any MD5 algorithm will produce the exact same result for the exact same input bytes, but you do need to make sure the input bytes are correct (and in particular, identical to any other place you hash the same data).